# InDesign template for calendar printing

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production, template

I am designing our company's annual calendar and to speed up the process I purchased [this](https://creativemarket.com/mikhailmorosin/732519-Wall-Calendar-2017) template.

My question is, the creator of the template set the pages up as 11x17" (so the image is at the top, and months are on the bottom) but don't they need to be broken up into 2 pages since it gets stapled in the middle?

I contacted the creator of the template but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: ...print it on 11x17 paper? That's what I do with the calendars I make every year.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you intend to do with this, but I would assume this template was intended for wall hanging, in portrait orientation, in which case the pages will get a spiral coil at the top, like this:

[image]